# Schrieb man früher "Beet" statt "Bett"?

Tags: word-usage, etymology, history

Im folgenden interessanten Text von Heine (vielleicht weniger bekannt als *Die Lorelei*)  schreibt er:

> Ich habe die friedlichste Gesinnung. Meine Wünsche sind: eine bescheidene Hütte, ein Strohdach, aber ein gutes Beet, gutes Essen, Milch und Butter, sehr frisch, vor dem Fenster Blumen, vor der Tür einige schöne Bäume, und wenn der liebe Gott mich ganz glücklich machen will, läßt er mich die Freude erleben, daß an diesen Bäumen etwa sechs bis sieben meiner Feinde aufgehängt werden.
>   (Heinrich Heine: Gedanken und Einfälle - Kapitel 1)

Ist hier *Beet* einfach als Variante von *Bett* zu interpretieren ?

Comment: Auch die heutige Bedeutung von *Beet* wäre hier inhaltlich passend.

Comment: Wo diese Stelle zitiert wird, habe ich überall nur "Bett" gefunden, man müsste auch einmal nachprüfen, ob sich da nicht ein Fehler eingeschlichen hat. Zitierst Du hier aus einen Buch auf Papier?

Comment: @Carsten: ich habe Projekt Gutenberg-DE  benutzt : http://gutenberg.spiegel.de/buch/-381/1  Auch bei Amazon.de kann man einen Auszug aus dem *Papier* Buch lesen ("Blick ins Buch"), in welchem tatsächlich *Beet* steht: http://www.amazon.de/Gedanken-Einf%C3%A4lle-TREDITION-CLASSICS-Heinrich/dp/3842490399/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1452250606&sr=1-1&keywords=Heinrich+Heine+Gedanken+und+Einf%C3%A4lle#reader_3842490399

Comment: Danke, den "Blick ins Buch" hatte ich nicht probiert und auch bei Amazon nur eine Version gefunden, bei der OCR hätte involviert gewesen sein können.

Answer (score 15):

Der Duden sagt Folgendes:

> mittelhochdeutsch bet(te), althochdeutsch betti, auch: Beet; **ursprüngliche Bezeichnung für das mit Stroh und Fellen gepolsterte Lager entlang den Wänden des germanischen Hauses und vielleicht eigentlich** = Polster

(Quelle: [Duden.de](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Bett))

Ebenso besagt er in einem anderen Artikel Folgendes:

> mittelhochdeutsch bette, althochdeutsch betti = Bett; Feld-, Gartenbeet, identisch mit Bett und **erst seit dem 17. Jahrhundert formal davon unterschieden**

Heine lebte im 18. und 19. Jahrhundert. Daher wurden dort - dem Duden zufolge - die beiden Wörter schon unterschieden. Vermutlich war also damit die *"ursprüngliche Bezeichnung für das mit Stroh und Fellen gepolsterte Lager entlang den Wänden des germanischen Hauses"* gemeint, was auch in diesem Kontext zum "Strohdach" passen würde.

Comment: Danke für Deine interessante Antwort, Giraffe. Was bedeutet eigentlich in diesem Zusammenhang  "Lager" ?

Comment: "Lager"  ist hier ein Platz zum Ausruhen

Comment: Danke für die Erklärung, @Iris.